# Ways to simplify my code - Multichoice quiz

Tags: python

This is a multi-choice quiz for kids where they input their age and the algorithm determines what quiz they do (A or B). People less than 8 will do Quiz A but people less than 5 will get a warning message that they are too young to play but can play if they want to. People older than 8 do Quiz B but people who are older than 11 get a warning message stating that they are too old to play but can play if they want to. Note: I don't really care about the repeats/play again right now just want a way to simplify the base structure of the code without using complicated stuff and classes. Thanks for reading!

```
questions = ["What is 1 + 1",
             "Who is the 45th president of the United States?",
             "True or False... The Toronto Maple Leafs have won 13 Stanley Cups?",
             "What was the last year the Toronto Maple Leafs won the Stanley Cup?",
             "True or False... The current Prime Minister of Canada is Pierre Elliot  Tredeau?"]
answer_choices = ["a)1\nb)2\nc)3\nd)4\n:",
                  "a)Barack Obama\nb)Hillary Clinton\nc)Donald Trump\nd)Tom Brady\n:",
                  ":",
                  "a)1967\nb)1955\nc)1987\nd)1994\n:",
                  ":"]
correct_choices = [{"b", "2"},
                   {"c", "donald trump"},
                   {"true", "t"},
                   {"a", "1967"},
                   {"false", "f"}]
answers = ["1 + 1 is 2",
           "The 45th president is Donald Trump",
           "",
           "The last time the Toronto Maple Leafs won the Stanley Cup was 1967",
           "The current Prime Minster of Canada is Justin Tredeau"]

questions_b = ["Who painted the Mona Lisa",
               "Which planet is closest to the sun?",
               "How many valves does the heart have?",
               "What nut is in the middle of a Ferrero Rocher?",
               "How many minutes in a game of rugby league?"]
answer_choices_b = ["a)Vincent Van Gogh\nb)Leonardo da Vinci\nc)Michelangelo\nd)Pablo Picasso\n:",
                    "a)Mercury\nb)Venus\nc)Mars\nd)Neptune\n:",
                    "a)Three\nb)One\nc)Five\nd)Four\n:",
                    "a)Walnut\nb)Hazelnut\nc)Almond\nd)Macadamias\n:",
                    "a)80 minutes\nb)60 minutes\nc)40 minutes\nd)20 minutes\n:"]
correct_choices_b = [{"b", "Leonardo da Vinci"},
                     {"a", "Mercury"},
                     {"d", "Four"},
                     {"b", "Hazelnut"},
                     {"a", "80 minutes"}]

answers_b = ["Leonardo da Vinci painted the Mona Lisa",
             "Mercury is the planet closest to the sun",
             "The heart has four valves",
             "A hazelnut is in the middle of a Ferrero Rocher",
             "There are 80 minutes in a game of rugby league"]
run = "y"


def quiz_a():
    score = 0
    for question, choices, correct_choice, answer in zip(questions, answer_choices, correct_choices, answers):
        print(question)
        user_answer = input(choices).lower()
        if user_answer in correct_choice:
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect", answer)
    print(score, "out of", len(questions), "that is", float(score / len(questions)) * 100, "%")



def quiz_b():
    score = 0
    for question, choices, correct_choice, answer in zip(questions_b, answer_choices_b, correct_choices_b, answers_b):
        print(question)
        user_answer = input(choices).lower()
        if user_answer in correct_choice:
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect", answer)
    print(score, "out of", len(questions), "that is", float(score / len(questions)) * 100, "%")


#start of program
#Quiz B is people age 8 to 11
#Quiz A is people less than 8 
age = int(input("How old are you?: "))
while run == "y":
    if age <= 5:
        leave = input("You are too young. Do you still want to play? y/n: ")
        if leave == "n":
            print("Goodbye")
            break
        elif leave == "y":
            print("Starting now. You will be doing Quiz A")
            quiz_a()
        else:
            break
    elif age > 11:
        leave = input("You are too old. Do you still want to play? y/n: ")
        if leave == "n":
            print("Goodbye")
            break
        elif leave == "y":
            print("Starting now. You will be doing Quiz B")
            quiz_b()
            play_again = input("Do you want to do the other quiz? y/n: ")
            if play_again.lower() == "y":
                print("Okay starting Quiz A")
                quiz_a()
                print("Thanks for playing! Goodbye")
                break
            else:
                print("Goodbye")
                break
        else:
            break
    elif age <= 5 and age < 8:
        print("Starting now. You will be doing Quiz A")
        quiz_a()
    else:
        if age <= 8:
            print("Starting now. You will be doing Quiz B")
            quiz_b()
```

Comment: The `quiz` functions are identical.  Just have one function, and pass the list of data structures into it.  Or, create a dict with, for example, keys like `"questions", "choices", "correct", and "answers"`, so you only have to pass ONE thing around.  That will make it easier to store this stuff in a file or database later.

Comment: the question may be better suited here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this using OOP. As you could see you can have Quiz class which represent a Quiz question, and to hold all questions you can create list of Quiz objects.

```
class Quiz(object):
"""docstring for Quiz."""

def __init__(self, question, options, answer):
    super(Quiz, self).__init__()
    self.question = question
    self.options = options;
    self.answer = answer

def show(self):
    print(self.question, self.options, self.answer)

q = Quiz("this is question", ["apple", "banana", "cherry"], 1)
q.show()
```